# Python Logic Issue: Test Scores

Tags: python, testing, logic

Hi all I'm a bit stuck with a logic problem.

The criteria is:

Write a program that asks the user to enter a number of test scores. The program should display a letter grade for each score and the average test score. Write the following functions in the program:

calc_average - This function should ask the user to enter in test scores until there are no more scores to enter, print the letter grade for each test score, and return the average of all test scores.
determine_grade - This function should accept a test score as an argument and return a letter grade for the score, based upon the following grading scale:

Score Scale:

90 - 100 A
80 - 89 B
70 - 79 C
60 - 69 D
Below 60 F

So the way I'm thinking about it is that I would have to create two functions calc_average and determine_grade.

The problem is that by having determine_grade() above calc_average() the score once entered from calc_average() can not be passed up to determine_grade() and so the letter grade can not be determined and be passed back down to be printed. So the problem becomes seemingly unsolvable (at least if one follows the instructions).

Please help me find a solution. Thanks

My code so far (not yet complete):

```
def determine_grade(grade):

    while 90 <= grade <= 100:
        g = "A"
    while 80 <= grade <= 89:
        g = "B"
    while 70 <= grade <= 79:
        g = "C"
    while 60 <= grade <= 69:
        g = "D"
    while grade < 60:
        g = "F"
    return g

def calc_average():

    c = "y"
    t = 0
    count = 0
    while c == "y" or c == "Y":
        s = float(input("Enter score: "))
        t +=s 
        count += 1
        g = determine_grade(s)
        print("Grade: " .format(g))
        avg = t/count
    return avg

a = calc_average()
print("Average: {0:.2f}" .format(a))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not having the loop and input outside both (actually I gave up on average since running average is dangerous)?

```
def determine_grade(grade):    
    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        return "A"
    if 80 <= grade <= 89:
        return "B"
    if 70 <= grade <= 79:
        return "C"
    if 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return "D"
    if grade < 60:
        return "F"
    return "error"

def main():
    grades = []
    cont = input("continue ('y')?")
    while cont == "y" or cont == "Y":
        grade = float(input("Enter score: "))
        print("Grade: " + determine_grade(grade))
        grades.append(grade)
        cont = input("continue ('y')?")
    print("Average: {0:.2f}" .format(sum(grades) / len(grades)))
```

Changes:

1. while loop is now outside of function(s). So you can pass anything from the main context to any function.
2. No need for `while` if you want to check a condition and return immediately. Use `if` (see `determine_grade`
3. Not taking input for `c` causes an infinite loop. Fixed.

Comment: So then the grade being called from main() can be passed to determine_grade(grade)? Ok I always thought that since determine_grade(grade) can not receive values from something that has not yet existed yet following the sequence order then it could not receive grade from main(). However, I guess I was wrong. Thanks for the help and clearing things up! : D